# Feynman-Kac formula for lattice heat equation with non-diagonal potential

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, stochastic-processes, differential-equations, operator-theory

Suppose that $X$ is the continuous-time simple symmetric random walk on the lattice $\mathbb Z^d$ (i.e., a simple symmetric random walk with i.i.d. exponential jump times), and let
$$u(t,x):=\mathbf E\left[\exp\left(\int_0^tV(X_s)~ds\right)f(X_t)\bigg|X_0=x\right]
\tag{1}$$
for $(t,x)\in[0,\infty)\times\mathbb Z^d$, where $V,f:\mathbb Z^d\to\mathbb R$ are functions.

According to the Feynman-Kac formula, we know that $u(t,x)$ solves the lattice/matrix heat equation
$$\partial_tu=\tfrac12\Delta u+Vu,\qquad u(0,x)=f(x),\tag{2}$$
where
$$\Delta:=\left[
\begin{array}{ccccc}
&\ddots&\ddots&\\
&\ddots&-2&1&\\
&&1&-2&1&\\
&&&1&-2&\ddots\\
&&&&\ddots&\ddots&
\end{array}\right]$$
is the discrete Laplacian, and we think of $V$ as the diagonal matrix
$$V=\left[
\begin{array}{ccccc}
&\ddots&&\\
&&V(-1)&&\\
&&&V(0)&&\\
&&&&V(1)&&\\
&&&&&\ddots&&
\end{array}\right].$$

---

As an alternative to $(2)$, a common model for a lattice heat equation is to consider
$$\partial_tu=\tfrac12\Delta u+\tilde Vu,\qquad u(0,x)=f(x),\tag{3}$$
where the potential $\tilde V$ is instead of the form
$$\tilde V=\left[
\begin{array}{ccccc}
&\ddots&\ddots&\\
&\ddots&0&V(-1)&\\
&&V(-1)&0&V(0)&\\
&&&V(0)&0&V(1)&\\
&&&&V(1)&0&\ddots\\
&&&&&\ddots&\ddots&
\end{array}\right],$$
or a more general tridiagonal matrix
$$\tilde V=\left[
\begin{array}{ccccc}
&\ddots&\ddots&\\
&\ddots&U(-1)&V(-1)&\\
&&V(-1)&U(0)&V(0)&\\
&&&V(0)&U(1)&V(1)&\\
&&&&V(1)&U(2)&\ddots\\
&&&&&\ddots&\ddots&
\end{array}\right].$$

---

> **Question.** Does there exist a Feynman-Kac formula *similar to* $(1)$ for lattice operators with non-diagonal potential such as $(3)$?

To clarify a bit what I mean by *similar to* $(1)$: It's easy enough to come up with *some* probabilistic representation of the solution of $(3)$ (for example by using the Trotter-Kato theorem: $e^{\Delta/2+V}\approx(e^{\Delta/2n}e^{V/n})^n$ for large $n$), but I can't get anything *nice* like $(1)$, and It's not clear to me if we should/shouldn't expect such a nice representation in those cases.

Comment: Is $\tilde V \ge 0$?

Comment: @Nawaf Bou-Rabee In the case that interests me yes, we do have $\tilde V\geq0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Feynman-Kac formula for (3) is given by (1) with $V$ replaced with $$\left[
\begin{array}{ccccc}
&\ddots&&\\
&&V(-2)+U(-1)+V(-1)&&\\
&&&V(-1)+U(0)+V(0)&&\\
&&&&V(0)+U(1) + V(1)&&\\
&&&&&\ddots&&
\end{array}\right].$$ and the stochastic process $X_t$ being the one generated by the following infinitesimal generator $$
L f(i) = \frac{1}{2} (f(i+1) - 2 f(i) + f(i-1)) + V(i) (f(i+1)-f(i)) + V(i-1) (f(i-1)-f(i)) \;.
$$

Comment: Interesting, I didn't think of this very simple "change of variables". I suppose in that case that the "niceness" of the Feynman-Kac formula depends somehow on how nice $V$ is, since we can obtain some rather unwieldy Markov process as a result.

Comment: "Change of variables" is an elegant way to describe it, and indeed, this stochastic representation of the solution to (3) crucially depends on $\tilde V \ge 0$.